# How to enabled cors in django1.1 with angular 7?

Tags: cors, angular7, django-1.11, django-cors-headers

I am trying to develop my front end in angular 7 and would like to make cors request to my server to get data.

Chrome and Firefox block preflight request.

Can someone point me to how to resolve this issue?

In my Django settings, I have done "CORS_ORIGIN_ALLOW_ALL=True" still the error persists.

Using plugins don't help. There is always an error regarding cors.

Answer (score 0):

Please, review this repositories:

[sandbox-angular](https://github.com/carlosgiralt/sandbox-angular)

[sandbox-django](https://github.com/carlosgiralt/sandbox-django)

Comment: I did use django-cors-headers, still no effect.